# Google Calendar API "403 Forbidden" after migration to new hosting

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I found a strange error after migration to new hosting.
We have moved our server from Moscow and London.

I added a new IP to Google Developers Console (178.79.158.44).

After that, a part of the IPA worked good:
1) "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo" is working good
2) But "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/$calendar_id/events" - always return "403 Forbidden" error

What am I doing wrong?

On the old server in Moscow, everything is still working well.

My project ID "rapid-arbor-522"

Comment: what are the scopes are you using? Did you enable calendar API in console? Are you using service account?

Comment: > what are the scopes are you using?  
   
We sending about 3-5 request / second.   
   
> Did you enable calendar API in console?   
   
Of Course! As I write this, we are all working perfectly on the old server, with the exact same settings.    
    
> Are you using service account?    
    
What do you mean?

Comment: We using scopes 'profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The fact was that the new server has been configured and IPv4 and IPv6.

And apparently, some requests went through IPv6 that has not been configured in the console.

Once I disabled ipv6 (sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1) it worked =)